# can't use img tag in a angular 2 jhipster project

Tags: angular, jhipster

I can't use img tag in a main.component.html file in jhipster project (angular 2) as below:

```
<a href="http://localhost:9000">
        <img src="../../../content/images/logonew.png" alt="This is logo"/>
</a>
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with error messages or additional information, this gives us nothing

Comment: Thank you. I found this issue on: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5333 and done.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a duplicate of https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5333, upgrade to Jhipster 4.1.0 or more recent